# No link light on Virgin Media Super Hub when connect a long network cable

Tags: router, ethernet, connection

I have recently subscribed to Virgin 100Mbps Vivid 100 service and it is working fine for 3 devices connected over ethernet cable.

I want to add a PC up in an outbuilding and the cable I use is quite long - probably 60 metres long.  I have checked the cable using a continuity ethernet tester and it passes.  I have also used the cable connected into other routers and it works there.

But when I connect the cable into the Virgin Super hub the link light does not light up and I get no network connectivity on this PC.  I would have assumed that if the connectivity check works then the link light should light up?

My idea would be to use a hub and connect the distant PC cable into the hub and then connect the hub into the Virgin router.

The maximum length for ethernet is 100m so surprised to find this issue.

UPDATE: I connected long cable via an ethernet hub and the link light lit up and I have a connection.  Why not on the Virgin hub?  It is this device:

http://www.techradar.com/reviews/virgin-media-super-hub-3

from Arris.

Comment: What is at the other end of the cable?

Comment: @music2myear a PC.

Comment: Ok, so there are 2 cables into the Virgin device: "uplink" and then the 60m one out to the PC. You mention your idea is to have the Virgin device and a hub at opposite ends of the long run, have you tried this yet?

Comment: @music2myear no to make it work I have an ethernet switch located next to the Virgin cable router.  long cable goes into ethernet switch, another cable goes from ethernet switch into cable router.  That works.